# I can't launch the application Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter

I recently downloaded android studio, opened a ready-made application and tried to launch it, but without success. I don't know why, I'm a beginner, but I did everything according to the instructions of the seller of the application and everything is configured correctly. Thanks !

error code:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on MI 8 Lite in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-3.0.0/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart:46:19: Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'.
      io.Platform.packageRoot; // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 40s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: can you add the code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see from your code, you are trying to run a Flutter application, which is a cross platform framework. You need to install the Flutter Package from the Plugins section in Android Studio and then try to run the application again.

Comment: I've set everything up, the Flutter and Dirt plugins are already installed